# Install PhantomJS on Qnap

Tags: phantomjs, qnap

I am using PhantomJS on Windows and would like to know if it is possible to install this program on Qnap ts-231?
Someone has already done? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the QNAP app: "container-station" (=Docker) to install "phantomJS" on your TS-231.

Answer (score 0):

As already has been suggested you can use the QNAP `container-station` app.

[image: Container Station App Icon]

The container station is a lightweight tool that will allow you to use Docker to spin up instances of lightweight Linux Operation Systems and other App virtualizations. Have a good read of of the [container-station documentation](https://www.qnap.com/solution/container_station/en/) for a better understanding.

To install an instance of `phantomJS` via the `container-station` app, just open up the `container-station` application by clicking on the icon on the main dashboard.

Once Container Station has opened up you will be opened up to the Container Station Overview page. On the left hand side you will have a menu.

[image: Container Station Menu]

From this menu select the `<create>` option.

In the main search box at the top of the new window enter `phantomJS`

[image: Container Station Search box]

If any dockerized applications are found the results will appear here. All you need to do is look for an instance that suits your needs and click on the `<install>` on the right hand side for the instance that you want.

[image: Container Station PhantomJS Search Results]

Once you click on `<install>` you will need to choice the version that you want, I'd suggest just choosing the latest.

[image: Container Station version select]

You will then need to fill in the `Create Container` window. You can allocate the max CPU and max Memory here, and if you want to the volumes paths to local folders instead of folders within the container this can be done here as well. Once you have filled everything in that you want to fill in, you can click `<Create>` and this will start downloading and installing your new Container for `PhantomJS`.

[image: Container Station Create Container]

This is pretty much the same for almost every other Docker app that can be installed via the `Container-Station` app.

*Please note that you may have additional setup for the application you are installing.*

Answer (score 0):

You can install a Docker Container through **Container Station** or a VM through **Virtualization Station** with phantomJS.

I've installed a VM with firefox, geckodriver and PhantomJS to develop some scrappers in Python.